# Why lazy loading doesn't work in my react project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, lazy-loading, code-splitting

I have a project: [link](https://github.com/tyt34/postcomm).

The project has router and lazy-components for every page.

**Short example router-component:**

```
export const RoutersComponent = () => {
  return (
    <HashRouter basename={'/'}>
      <Routes>
        <Route
          path="/"
          element={<Navigate replace to={routerConfig.log.url} />}
        />
        <Route
          path={routerConfig.reg.url}
          element={<LazyRegistrationPage />}
        />
        <Route
          path={routerConfig.log.url}
          element={<LazyLogginPage />}
        />
      </Routes>
    </HashRouter>
  )
}
```

*Full component **router** on [link](https://github.com/tyt34/postcomm/blob/main/src/router.js).*

**Short example lazy-component:**

Folder src/pages/registration

File index.js

```
export * from './registration'
export * from './lazy'
```

File lazy.js

```
import { Suspense, lazy } from 'react'
import { Loading } from '../../components'

const Registration = lazy(() =>
  import('./registration').then((module) => ({
    default: module.Registration
  }))
)

export const LazyRegistrationPage = () => {
  return (
    <Suspense fallback={"Loading..."}>
      <Registration />
    </Suspense>
  )
}
```

Short file registration.js:

```
export const Registration = () => {
  return (
    <section className="log">
      Registration
    </section>
  )
}
```

*Full component **registration** on [link](https://github.com/tyt34/postcomm/tree/main/src/pages/registration)*

I use library:

```
"react": "^18.1.0",
"react-dom": "^18.1.0",
"react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
```

If i start command:

```
npm run build
```

then i will get one file ***.js

But why???

In my short project everything is working:

```
import { Suspense, lazy } from "react";
import "./App.css";

const A = lazy(() =>
  import("./A").then((module) => ({
    default: module.A,
  }))
);

const LazyA = () => {
  return (
    <Suspense fallback={"loading..."}>
      <A />
    </Suspense>
  );
};

const B = lazy(() => import("./B"));

const LazyB = () => {
  return (
    <Suspense fallback={"loading..."}>
      <B />
    </Suspense>
  );
};

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="App">hello</div>
      <LazyA />
      <LazyB />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

After build I have 4 file ***.js.

I don't understand.

Comment: The way you are trying to code-split/lazy-load seems a little unconventional. Even more so with the routing code. Check the [official example](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/tree/dev/examples/lazy-loading) to see if you can get something that aligns more with the established pattern.

Comment: i repeat from this link and dont work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is often the case, when you ask something that no one wants to understand, you find the answer yourself.

If you make a checkout for this commit "*7089bce*" in the project in the "*main*" branch, then you can find the file "***index.js***" on this path "*src/pages/index.js*". If shorter:

```
git clone https://github.com/tyt34/postcomm.git
git checkout 7089bce
vim src/pages/index.js
```

The contents of which:

```
// file on path: src/pages/index.js
export * from './all-posts-page'
export * from './all-users-page'
export * from './loggin'
export * from './post-page'
export * from './profile-page'
export * from './registration'
```

Due to such an import architecture, there was a problem with the *lazy loading*.

That is, it does not matter that in the end such a page component as:

```
export const Registration = () => <div>Example</div>
```

Used in *lazy loading* as a module, for example:

```
const Registration = lazy(() =>
  import('./registration').then((module) => ({
    default: module.Registration
  }))
)

export const LazyRegistrationPage = () => {
  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
      <Registration />
    </Suspense>
  )
}
```

The  "***index.js***" file that was shown above crossed out everything.